# Excel VBA Macro to autofill (ie. filldown) AFTER last row to the next blank row?

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

I have data that I require to count down with the rows. The problem is that the column of data (Column A) contains both letters and numbers (as per image). 
[image: Image 1]

I figured that the simplest way around this is by using the either the filldown/autofill function. Essentially: find the end of the data and autofill to the next blank cell in the row below.

Currently, my VBA code looks like this:

```
    Dim LastRow, currentCol As Long
    currentCol = 1 'change to whatever row you want to work with
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, currentCol).End(xlDown).Row
    End With

    Cells(LastRow, currentCol).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(LastRow, currentCol), Cells(LastRow, currentCol).Offset(1, 0)), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

If you have any fixes or alternatives, I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: `Cells` arguments are *rows*, *columns*. You've got it backwards. Also, use `Long` instead of `Integer`.

Comment: Thanks for that! Still having issues with the last line.

Comment: `LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, currentCol).End(xlDown).Row` - this is always the *last* row of the spreadsheet. You're starting at the last row (`.Rows.Count`) and using `End(xlDown)`, which is still the last row.

Comment: What @BigBen means is that you need to use `End(xlUp)` to get from the last row of the spreadsheet to the last row with data.

Comment: Okay, awesome! I've got it working. Thank you both for your help! I really appreciate it